# Guardar en una variable el archivo excel que acabo de generar con php

Tags: php, excel, guardar

**Necesito guardar el archivo excel generado dentro de una variable, y dicha variable poder retornar.
Se los agradeceria cualquier ayuda.**

Gracias.
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('contrato proveedores');

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Contrato de proveedores AT.xls');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$variable = '';
try 
{
    $variable = $objWriter->save('php://output');
} 
catch (PHPExcel_Writer_Exception $e) 
{
    echo json_encode(["error" => $e]);
    exit;
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "path" => $variable
));
exit;
```

Comment: ¿Quieres enviar el archivo en un atributo `path` de un json?

Comment: Sii, exacto, una vez que el phpexcel lo genera, quiero que eso se almacene en una variable, para así esa variable pasarlo a mi js.

Comment: Aunque en un atributo `path` se esperaría encontrar una ruta y no contenido; en lugar de mandar el .xls a `php://output` mándalo a un [archivo temporal](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php), para después [obtener el contenido](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents) de dicho archivo convertido a [base64](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php).

Comment: hay varias formas de hacerlo, basado en mi opinión es la siguiente: 1) generar un `string` tipo `blob` del archivo y colocarlo en un tag `object`; para que al darle click se descargue el archivo... 2) generar el archivo en el disco duro en un carpeta publica para el sitio ... y pasar el `path` en un `link` ... para que pueda ser descargado al hacer click...

Comment: Sii, tal cual me indicas el punto 2, lo realice, idéntico a como me dices, no tenia otra idea y pues lo hice así, pero lo voy a intentar haciéndolo como explicas en tu punto 1,. Muchas gracias por la info, se agrdece, saludos.